# How to close FlyoutAnchor its overlaps the parent element by using protractor

Tags: angular, selenium, firefox, webdriver, protractor

when we click on FlyoutAnchor its open the menu items, we need to close that menu items (manually we can close by clicking on parent (FlyoutAnchor) control ), but focus is not coming to FlyoutAnchor because menu items are overlaps the FlyoutAnchor control.

we tried with pressing the escape button by the help of below code, but this code not working on firefox browser (open issue).

**browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();**

can any one help me how to archive this.

[image for the control](http://[IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/5vr7g7.png[/IMG])

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? Typically nav doesn't overlap the parent control once opened.

Comment: [IMG]http://i65.tinypic.com/4nseh.png[/IMG]

Comment: sorry, jeffC currently our application is not in the live,  Here nav is not completyly overlaps the parent control. you can see the above image (Microsoft word online) its same as our control.

Comment: sometimes you have to send the escape key to an actual element on the page to make it work `element(by.css('body')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE)`